# How to add Azure Application Insights to a .NET Core App?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-analysis-services

How does one add Azure Application Insights to a .NET Core App? I want to see search traffic analytics.

Comment: Is this a .net core console app or .net core web app?

Answer (score 4):

An overall solution that would work locally, on both Windows and on Linux* environments, is:

1. Create an Application Insights account.
2. Install the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` NuGet package
3. Using Dependency Injection, register the Application Insights client into the service collection. You can find [a very good example on how to do this](https://andrewlock.net/using-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-console-application/) on Andrew Lock's blog.
4. Register Application Insights telemetry insight your `Startup` class. It will work out of the box for you later on.

   ```cs
   services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
   ```
5. Add `ApplicationInsights` in your `appsettings` file, and `InstrumentationKey` inside of it (Your instrumentation key can be found in the overview tab of your resource):

   ```json
   "ApplicationInsights": {
     "InstrumentationKey": "…"
   },
   ```

Now, if you run your application, you will be able to capture all traffic in your Application Insights account.

* On Linux, this is currently in preview on Azure, but this would work.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same way you do for ASP.NET app. Did you have a chance to look at [Start Monitoring Your ASP.NET Core Web Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/dotnetcore-quick-start) which includes the same steps

- Create AppInsights
- Enable AppInsights
- Configure App Insights SDK

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated my Visual Studios but I do not see nor have the option to add Application Insights Telemetry to my project, this is the part I'm getting stuck at.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in Visual Studio, right click in project you want to add the Application insights and click Publish. Go to Connected Services, inside Service Dependencies, click Add Dependency and select Application Insights Sdk (Local) as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Click Next then click Finish to install the required Nuget packages and you're done.